# XMLSyntaxError: Premature end of data in tag _io.TextIOWrapper - Python

Tags: python, xml-parsing, syntax-error

I am getting an error : "XMLSyntaxError: Premature end of data in tag _io.TextIOWrapper line 1, line 1, column 119" and I don't understand why... I checked my XML file for any left open brackets but nothing...

Ideas?

Thanks a lot !

```
<Motor>
    <Materials_database>

        <Material name="Steel1">

            <CurveProperties>

                <Data Temperature="427" Start="2.4e+03" Stop="1.2e+05"></Data>

                <Data Temperature="760" Start="1e+03" Stop="2e+05"></Data>

                <Data Temperature="871" Start="2.4e+03" Stop="1.2e+05"></Data>

                <Data Temperature="982" Start="2.4e+03" Stop="1.2e+05"></Data>

            </CurveProperties>

        </Material>

    </Materials_database> 

</Motor>
```

Python code:

```
with open(os.getcwd() + '\\materials.xml', "r" , encoding="utf-8") as dtfile:
    temp, start, stop = f.Get_MaterialDatabase(str(dtfile), matName)
```

Function:

```
def Get_MaterialDatabase(xml, MaterialName):

  Motor = objectify.fromstring(xml)                             
  for mat in Motor.Material_database.iterchildren():
    xmlMat = mat.get("name")
    print (xmlMat)
    if xmlMat == MaterialName:
        temp = mat.CurveProperties.get("Temperature")
        start = mat.CurveProperties.get("Start")
        stop = mat.CurveProperties.get("Stop")

return temp, start, stop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you first have to read the content of the file `Get_MaterialDatabase(str(dtfile.read()), matName)`

And it is `for mat in Motor.Materials_database.iterchildren():` (Material**s**)

And the fields are in the object `Data`

```
  temp = mat.CurveProperties.Data.get("Temperature")
  start = mat.CurveProperties.Data.get("Start")
  stop = mat.CurveProperties.Data.get("Stop")
```

You have multiple `Data` tags in `CurveProperties`, be sure to handle the list of `Data` tags.

Next time you have such an error try a debugger and see what the value of the variable is, or a simple print statement `print('xml=', xml)`

Since Windows XP you don't need to use the '\' as a directory separator in program code: `os.getcwd() + '/materials.xml'`